# SharePoint Provider hosted app with backend as sql server for CRUD operation

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sql, apps-development, crud

I have a provider hosted app in SharePoint on premise. Is it possible to retrieve data from sql server and crud operation database using app?

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely possible. You can work with the data stored in database inside your provider hosted application just like you would from the "normal" asp mvc web application.

Define your connection string, write code and create pages like the SharePoint doesn't even exist.